# How to add a checkbox to the listcontrol column header to check and uncheck all checkboxes of the list items?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Currently I am working on a listcontrol,where the first column header should consists of a checkbox.Adding checkbox to the list items can be done by setting the style to LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES.Is there any way to add checkbox to the header so that if I check it all the items in the list should get checked and if I uncheck it all the list items should get unchecked.

Can anyone please let me know any possible way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to get the checkbox on the header and using that checkbox on the header we can check and uncheck all the items in the list.

In the OnInitDialog() Add this below piece of code:

```
BOOL OnInitDialog()
{
    LVCOLUMN pColumn = {0};
   pColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;

   m_listCtrl.GetColumn(0, &pColumn);
   pColumn.fmt |= HDF_CHECKBOX;
   pColumn.pszText = L"";
   pColumn.cx = 25;
   pColumn.iSubItem = 1;

   m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, &pColumn);//m_listctrl is listcontrol member variable

}
```

Add this event HDN_ITEMSTATEICONCLICK

```
   void CMFPSearchListView::OnHdnItemStateIconClickListctrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMHEADER pNMHeader = (LPNMHEADER)pNMHDR;

    // first determine whether the click was a checkbox change
    if (pNMHeader->pitem->mask & HDI_FORMAT && pNMHeader->pitem->fmt & HDF_CHECKBOX)
    {
        // now determine whether it was checked or unchecked
        BOOL bUnChecked = pNMHeader->pitem->fmt & HDF_CHECKED;

        // apply check state to each list item
        for (int nItem = 0; nItem < m_listCtrl.GetItemCount(); nItem++)
            m_listCtrl.SetCheck(nItem, !bUnChecked);
    }


   *pResult = 1;   //if pResult = 0 then you will get blue color selection on the items when you check header checkbox , in order to avoid that I made pResult = 1; Now we won't face the selection issue.
    }
```

//Add LVN_ITEMCHANGED

```
void OnListViewItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
LVCOLUMN pColumn = {0};
pColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
m_listCtrl.GetColumn(0, &pColumn);
if(blAllChecked)
    pColumn.fmt |= HDF_CHECKED;
else
    pColumn.fmt &= ~HDF_CHECKED;


//m_listCtrl.InsertColumn(1, &pColumn);
m_listCtrl.SetColumn(0, &pColumn);
*pResult=0;    
}
```

Note:This header checkbox will work from above Windows XP Operating system.

Comment: May be this would be better rephrased as ""will work beginning in the Windows Vista Operating System".

Comment: I have the problem reported on https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/819824-c-listview/ : Checkbox on header does not appear without having the extended style LVS_EX_AUTOCHECKSELECT and I want to NOT have it.

Comment: Another observation: The combobox appears for `CListCtrl`/`CHeaderCtrl`, but not for `CMFCListCtrl`/`CMFCHeaderCtrl`! GRRRRR

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, it is very likely the feature of having a checkbox on header for `CMFCListCtrl`/`CMFCHeaderCtrl`is not even implemented, as I don't find occurences of  `HDS_CHECKBOXES`, `HDF_CHECKBOX` and `HDF_CHECKED` on the `afxheaderctrl.cpp|h` and `afxlistctrl.cpp|h` files!

Comment: My problem is solved by the http://stackoverflow.com/a/41205752/383779 to my question!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was very helpful, but using `LVCOLUMN` did not worked well for me.

so I found out using `HDITEM` working better for me:

```
CHeaderCtrl* pHeaderControl = m_ListControl.GetHeaderCtrl();

HDITEM hdi = { 0 };
hdi.mask   = HDI_FORMAT;
pHeaderControl->GetItem(0, &hdi);
hdi.fmt |= HDF_CHECKBOX;

if (bAllChecked)
{
    hdi.fmt |= HDF_CHECKED;
}
else
{
    hdi.fmt &= ~HDF_CHECKED;
}
pHeaderControl->SetItem(0, &hdi);
```