# How to add a checkbox style item to the header of Listview?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to add a checkbox style item to the header of Listview, but it doesn't work. Here is what I do:
In MainWndProc

```
case WM_CREATE:{
  HWND hHeader = CreateWindowEx(0,WC_HEADER,L"Header Control",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | HDS_CHECKBOXES,
            10, 10, 1000, 20,hWnd,(HMENU)ID_HEADER,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
  HDITEM hdi;
  hdi.mask = HDI_FORMAT | HDI_WIDTH;
  hdi.cxy = 100;
  hdi.fmt = HDF_CHECKBOX;

  int index = SendMessage(hHeader, HDM_INSERTITEM,
    (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)&hdi);
}
```

the result is here:

[image]

I also tried some other api or marco like Header_SetItem and Header_InsertItem, but checkbox didn't appear either. The question in [How to add a checkbox to the listcontrol column header to check and uncheck all checkboxes of the list items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687172/)  is exactly what I want to do, but I don't want to use MFC. Can I do this work only use the HDITEM structure and Header_InsertItem? It's my first time to ask question in stack overflow. If there is any unclear information in my question, please tell me. Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: Your code is creating your own Header control, but your question is about a ListView control. A ListView has its own Header, which you can access by using `ListView_GetHeader()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your picture, it seems you aren't using visual styles.

You must use Common Control 6.0 or later version.
This flag doesn't work without visual styles.

See [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)